# Mark-as-duplicate vs. Merge

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

I want to know the exact difference between questions marked as duplicates vs. merged questions.
For example, I think answers are also redirected to the original question with which a second question is merged, whereas if it is marked as a duplicate, then this is not the case.

I want to know **all differences between them** and why both are displayed as [duplicate], or why [merged] is not used.
Which (mark-as-duplicate or merge) is used and when?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exact duplicate is **closed** question. It and its answers can be voted on or edited and comments can be added.  But you can't post answer to this question, or start a bounty on it.

Merged question is an exact duplicate that was **locked** and its answers were moved to the question which was used to close as duplicate. Merged question can't be voted on or edited, no comments and answers can be added. Merge can be performed only by moderators.